# Tradução de textos no resultado do Google

Tags: debate, tradução

Ao se buscar "Stack Overflow" no Google o primeiro resultado trazido é o https://pt.stackoverflow.com, porém os textos associados ao link estão em inglês.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> By using our site, you acknowledge that you have read and understand our ...

Assim como das páginas internas: "Stack Overflow is the largest, most trusted online community for...", "By clicking Publicar sua pergunta, you agree to our terms of...", etc.

Acredito que essa mistura de idiomas possa confundir um usuário que chega ao site através desses links, uma vez que não fica explícito de antemão o idioma da página.

É possível, de alguma forma, efetuar a tradução desses textos?

Comment: Acho que somente a SE Inc consegue mudar a meta descrição (meta desciption) do site, não acho que os moderadores possuam permissão para isso.

Comment: @danieltakeshiCorreto. Já conversei com o NIcolas sobre isso, só abri a pergunta aqui para deixar registrado e ele poder responder oficialmente quando puder.

Comment: Só para constar, esse texto "By using our site, you acknowledge that you have read and understand our" é vindo da versão mobile do site http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Yomb8J4iVWAJ:https://pt.stackoverflow.com/&client=firefox-b-d&hl=pt-BR&gl=br&strip=0&vwsrc=1, **inclusive** na tag HTML contém `<html lang="en">`, então o problema todo é causado por esta versão, não sei porque o google está dando prioridade a versão mobile, mas creio que fora melhorar as traduções no mobile falta ajustar algo no "webtools".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Entrei em contato com o Nicolas e conseguimos traduzir os textos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ainda há o "By clicking..." junto ao link "Faça uma Pergunta", que já foi traduzido no Traducir.win (https://pt.traducir.win/string/10476) e, possivelmente, em breve será indexado pelo Google também.